# For /F binary reg value neq (result = always success)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, if-statement, hex, registry

What I'm I missing?

I try to grab a binary key value from `UserPreferencesMask`, the binary value is `9032078010000000` (or `hex:90,32,07,80,10,00,00,00` in `regedit`).

Result `%%A` does print `9032078010000000`, but when I use this result in/with `if %% NEQ` or `EQU` I always `goto:HEX_okay`.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3 delims= " %%A in ('reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /f UserPreferencesMask /d /T REG_BINARY') do (
  echo.RESULT="%%A"
  REM if %%a NEQ 9032078010000000 goto FiX
  if %%A EQU 9032038010000000 goto HEX_okay
  goto:FiX
)
```

I use `skip=2` because I don't use the first `2` lines,
and `delims= "` to skip to the `3rd` token, sort of speak...

**edit:**

The *UserPreferencesMask* has to be `9032078010000000` (binary value), if not, change it to this specific binary value (use reg add).

**ie.** `REG.exe ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V "UserPreferencesMask" /T REG_BINARY /D "9032078010000000" /F`

I also tried:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v UserPreferencesMask /t REG_BINARY') do (
  echo.RESULT="%%i"
  IF NOT %%i equ 9032038010000000 goto FiX
  IF %%i equ 9032038010000000 goto HEX_okay
  goto:DO_NOTING
)
```

...But with same result and changing `equ` into `==` doesn't help either.

when I change the value for *UserPreferencesMask* in regedit and place *aa* (or what ever) I do get some result; `goto FiX`. BUT when I just add some numbers (in regedit) then I always `goto HEX_okay`, so annoying :'(

These next changes (below) don't help either, then it's always, `goto FIX`:

```
  IF NOT "%%i"=="9032038010000000" goto FiX
  IF "%%i"=="9032038010000000" goto HEX_okay
```

**These** next lines do seem to "work", WELL SORT OFF:

when I change the binary value of "UserPreferencesMask" like a lot than just 1 or 2 digits, then it does seem to work as expected...
Weird and not completely 'monkey proof', it's NOT always doing as expected.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3 delims= " %%i in ('reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /F "UserPreferencesMask" /D /C /E /T REG_BINARY') do (
  echo.RESULT="%%i"
  IF NOT %%i equ 9032038010000000 goto FiX
  IF %%i equ 9032038010000000 goto HEX_okay
  goto:NO_UserPreferencesMask
)
```

**PS.** I can use `for /f "tokens=3"` for the same result though

This **workaround** does seem to function though:

```
reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /F "UserPreferencesMask" /D /C /E /T REG_BINARY | find /i "9032078010000000"
    if errorlevel 1 goto FiX
    if errorlevel 0 goto HEX_okay
```

Comment: You are exceeding the 32 bit integer limit for a numeric comparison so you have to compare them as strings.  `if "9032038010000000" equ "9032038010000001" echo yes` or `if "9032038010000000"=="9032038010000001" echo yes`

Comment: If you are just wanting to check against a specific value, you don't need a `for` loop. However, if `:FiX` entails modifying that registry key you may need to store it for further use, _(it may just be easier to overwrite the value with `9032078010000000` regardless of its current value)_. In your code I'd suggest you perform a string comparison too, `If "%%A"=="9032078010000000"` and `If Not "%%A"=="9032078010000000"`. Perhaps a little more code or explanation would help us to put the code into context better before providing advice or solutions.

Comment: The UserPreferencesMask has to be 9032078010000000 (binary value), of not, change it to this value (reg add). ie. REG.exe ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V "UserPreferencesMask" /T REG_BINARY /D "9032078010000000" /F

Comment: @Compo it does not seem to work, I added:
  IF "%%A"=="9032038010000000" goto HEX_okay
  IF NOT "%%A"=="9032038010000000" goto FiX

Comment: when I change the value in regedit an place aa (or what ever) I do get a result; goto FiX. BUT when I just add some numbers (in regedit) dan I allways goto HEX_okay, so annoying :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it using `Reg.exe` in a `For` loop:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "DUPM=9032078010000000"
Set "MASK="
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    'Reg Query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V UserPreferencesMask'
) Do If /I Not "%%B"=="%DUPM%" Set "MASK=%%B"
If Not Defined MASK GoTo HEX_okay

:FiX
Echo The value data %MASK% needs fixing!
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:HEX_okay
Echo The value data matches %DUPM%!
Pause
GoTo :EOF
```

**Edit**
Based upon your comment, and given that you're still not using the `Reg Query` options correctly/efficiently, here is how you should perform that task:

```bat
@Echo Off
Reg Query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V UserPreferencesMask|Find /I "9032078010000000" >Nul && GoTo HEX_okay

:FiX
Echo The value data needs fixing!
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:HEX_okay
Echo The value data matches!
Pause
GoTo :EOF
```

Side note: as mentioned in my comments why aren't you simply adding the key? *If the existing key matches, overwriting it will not matter, if it doesn't you've changed it:*

```bat
Reg Add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V UserPreferencesMask /T REG_BINARY /D 9032078010000000 /F>Nul
```

Comment: awesome, this works, really appreciated.
Used this as an alternative, but now I can use your example, great...
`reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /F "UserPreferencesMask" /D /C /E /T REG_BINARY | find /i "9032078010000000"
    if errorlevel 1 goto FiX
    if errorlevel 0 goto HEX_okay`

AND learned some nice thing, thank you.

Comment: @APOC, I have added an **Edit** to my answer to show you how you should approach the method you've used in the above comment. However, as mentioned in a previous comment I still don't understand why you're not simply adding the key. If the key matches, overwriting it will not matter: `Reg Add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V UserPreferencesMask /T REG_BINARY /D 9032078010000000 /F>Nul`